# Compacting Shared Libraries in R package

Tags: r, rcpp, r-package

My package `.so` file is above 3 MB (up to 10 MB) depending of the compiler and the system. This generates a NOTE with `R CMD check` in my package for years. My package does not contain so much code so I eventually searched to reduce the size and I found this [excellent post](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2017/08/14/#009_compact_shared_libraries) by Dirk Eddelbuettel.

Following the advice I added `SHLIB_CXX11LDFLAGS = -Wl,-S -shared` in my `.R/Makevars` and my library size dropped from 10.4 MB to 580 KB!! For the first time I have 0 ERRORS, 0 WARNINGS and 0 NOTES. Yeah!

However this is only a **local** solution. At the end of the post the following is suggested for `src/Makevars`

```
strippedLib: $(SHLIB)
        if test -e "/usr/bin/strip"; then /usr/bin/strip --strip-debug $(SHLIB); fi

.phony: strippedLib
```

But it is mentioned that:

> And this scheme may even pass muster with CRAN, but I have not yet tried.

My questions are the following:

- The post is from Aug 2017. Does somebody knows if it passes CRAN check?
- This is a GNU/Linux (maybe macOS) solution. Is there a cross-platform option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot put it in `src/Makevars`. I just had to revert this myself in a package where the powers-that-be [noticed it](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppclassic/commit/1d5de422fa96596c575c1063fa84a52695398577).

But then, confusingly, we also have

```
edd@rob:~$ grep -i strip /etc/R/Makeconf     # convenience softlink on Debian/Ubuntu
STRIP_STATIC_LIB = strip --strip-debug
STRIP_SHARED_LIB = strip --strip-unneeded
edd@rob:~$
```

but I haven't yet had time to search if/where these are used.  So I still do

```
edd@rob:~$ grep -i strip ~/.R/Makevars 
STRIP=-Wl,-S
SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS = $(STRIP) -shared
SHLIB_CXX11LDFLAGS = $(STRIP) -shared
SHLIB_CXX14LDFLAGS = $(STRIP) -shared
SHLIB_FCLDFLAGS = $(STRIP) -shared
SHLIB_LDFLAGS = $(STRIP) -shared
edd@rob:~$
```

which is local-only.

*Edit:* Something I keep forgetting is the recently added `--strip` option for the installer:

```
edd@rob:~$ R CMD INSTALL --help | grep strip
      --strip           strip shared object(s)
edd@rob:~$
```

which can also be enable by setting the environment variable `_R_SHLIB_STRIP_` to a true value -- see a recent NEWS file for R.

Comment: At least I will recompile all my packages with this option. Thanks.

Comment: For absolute clarity, what you are saying is, we can put `_R_SHLIB_STRIP_ = 1` in our `src/Makevars` file?

Comment: It is an environment variable so you would but it in `.Renviron` and alike -- see `help(Startup)` as always. I also put it into `install.r` and friends from the littler package.  More details in the NEWS file:  https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/doc/NEWS.Rd#L1120-L1123 (though the line numbers in the link will get stale/wrong over time).